# Divagation or deviations

Tags: differences

I'm working on a hospital scheduling software which uses the term *divagation* whenever there's a change in employee's base schedule. When a nurse or a doctor works overtime, changes shifts, calls in sick, has compensatory time off etc. a list of these incidents called divagations is generated. This term doesn't sit well with me, but I cannot find another word for it except maybe deviations.

Are there any brighter ideas than mine out there? :)

Comment: Will _digressions_ be a better word?

Comment: Can you explain why your software should use a different word from what the hospital already uses? Surely it is not your job to reinvent their terminology. Why would you want to introduce new vocabulary and confuse them?  This is a genuine question.

Comment: It is my job. Please stay on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty obscure word and it doesn't have very positive overtones ([ramble, wander](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/divagation)). Why not **schedule change**?

Comment: **Schedule change** is both easy to understand and descriptive. I like it. My main concern, however, is that it sounds too nice? Some of the changes are not in compliance with our country's labour laws, like when a surgeon has to work overtime in order to save a patient. Labour law violations like these have to be justified by the employer in order to be approved. What I really need is a catch-all term which encompasses everything. Schedule change, however, is miles better than what we currently have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would title it "Variation" (uncountable)

OED:

> **4.a. The fact of varying in condition, character, degree, or other quality; the fact of undergoing modification or alteration, especially within certain limits.**